# python: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_mesa.so.0: undefined symbol: xcb_dri3_get_supported_modifiers

Tags: python, linux

I installed kivy in Debian OS and run sample kivy file but showing error.

> python: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_mesa.so.0: undefined symbol: xcb_dri3_get_supported_modifiers